# How to calculate fields sum in an ActiveRecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models :

```
module Purchases
  class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'invoices'
    belongs_to :order
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

and

```
module Purchases
  class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'line_items'
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :invoice
  end
end
```

I would like to get (for the current_month) the sum of :

- invoice.shipping_price_without_tax
- line_item.price * line_item.quantity
- line_items.quantity

`current_month = Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month`

```
@invoices = Purchases::Invoice.joins(:line_items)
                                     .where(created_at: current_month)
                                     .select('SUM(shipping_price_without_tax) AS total_shipping, SUM(line_items.price * line_items.quantity) AS total_price, SUM(line_items.quantity) AS total_quantity')
```

but get an error :

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Purchases::Invoice id: nil>]>
```

Comment: That's not an error. The objects in `@invoices` should have `total_shipping`, `total_price`, ... methods.

Comment: Unless `current_month` is actually a range you'll only get records that match it exactly. You want `.where(created_at: Date.current.beginning_of_month..Date.current.end_of_month)` or `.where("DATE_TRUNC('month', invoices.created_at) = ?", Date.current.beginning_of_month).
`

Comment: Its also very unclear what you actually expect the output to be - you're not actually selecting any columns from invoices besides the aggregates or using any grouping. If you just want aggregates then use `pluck` or `select_all` instead of the normal query methods that return model instances. It doesn't actually make sense to work with model instances that don't actually behave like single rows of the table they are selected from as thats kind of the basic tenet of ActiveRecord.

Comment: @muistooshort 

Invoice have shipping_price_without_tax and line_items have price and quantity

Comment: @max I would like to have all invoice beetwen to date :
SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."created_at" BETWEEN $1 AND $2  [["created_at", "2023-04-01"], ["created_at", "2023-04-30"]]

Comment: @max... maybe ;)

I have a shop, I would like to have the sum of different fields for the current month. For example, how many sales I made (line_item.price * line_item.quantity), or the total sum of shipping costs (sum(invoice.shipping_price)